# Ajax searching error Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have an error when searching for data from a database using ajax and codeigniter. When I search data their is another field shown. However, my code is just 1 field. Please help me.

This my code:

```
function refreshtable() {
   var kategori = $("#kategori").val();
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: "category="+kategori,
       url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>category/search",
       beforeSend: function() {
           $(".well-content").html("<div class='loading_div'><img src='<?php echo base_url() ?>img/loading.gif'></div>");
       },
       success: function(msg) {
           $("#tabledata").html(msg);
           // applyPagination();
       }
   });
   return false;
}
```

HTML code is

```
<div style="float:right;">
  <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" onkeyup="return refreshtable()" id="kategori" name="category" placeholder="Nama Kategori  ">
</div>
```

Controller code is

```
            function search($limit='',$offset=''){

    $this->load->model("category_model"); 

    $data['judul']='Master category';

    if($limit==''){ $limit = 0; $offset=10 ;}

    if($limit!=''){ $limit = $limit ; $offset=$this->offset ;}

    $data['count']=$this->category_model->countcategory();

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'category/search/';

    $config['total_rows'] = $data['count'];

    $config['per_page'] = $this->limit;    

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="pg">';

    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';       

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['query']=$this->category_model->searching($limit,$offset);

    $this->load->view('category/listdatacategory',$data);
}
```

Model code is

```
    function searching($limit='',$offset='',$id=''){


$category=$this->input->post('category');



    $query=$this->db->query("select *  from category where name like '%$category%'");



if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

foreach ($query->result() as $data) {

    $datac[]=$data;
        }
    return $datac;
    }
```

Comment: <div style="float:right;">

<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" onkeyup="return refreshtable()" id="categori" name="category" placeholder="Nama Kategori  ">

</div>

Comment: data:{category: kategori} - Also show us your search() function under the category controller.

Comment: @user3292721 where is your `search` function? What is the response of your ajax request?

Comment: @CosminPascu I have added controller and model. searching is work, but when searching for a data the field shown twice